# VS 2010 Remote debugging not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Hey everyone, I'm having trouble configuring my remote debugging set up. I've been searching and reading for a while, but I can't figure it out. I'm running windows 7 as the pc I'm running VS on and then have windows 7 running in virtual box as the pc that is running the program I'm trying to debug. I'm trying to debug a .NET 4 project.

Both computers are not part of a domain (I'm not sure if that matters). I'm running the debug monitor on the virtual pc via a shared folder on the non-virtual pc.

When I try to connect to the remote pc in the attach to process window in VS it connects, but fails to launch, and I get an error that says

```
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging.
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

Let me know if I need to say anything else about my set-up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you verified that there are no firewalls blocking the remote debugging ports?  If using Windows Firewall then add Visual Studio to the exception list.

Comment: I haven't touched the firewall other than the changes windows makes when running the debug monitor.

Comment: I never trusted when Windows would "help you out" by opening up the ports like that.  It is always best to double check that an exception was created for Visual Studio on your server machine.  You mentioned it wasn't on a domain but if both machines are connected to the same router then it is possible that the router firewall could be blocking these ports as well.  Barring a firewall issue, you must ensure that the application assemblies hosted on the server have been built in Debug mode and NOT Release mode.  Release mode is trimmed down and doesn't contain debug symbols.

Comment: It turned out I didn't have the firewall setup correctly, but I disabled the windows firewall for each machine and then tried again, but it still didn't work. It's still giving the same access denied error.

Comment: And the router firewall if applicable?  Did you confirm that the application was built in Debug mode?

Comment: It's being built in debug mode, and I don't think the router firewall is an issue. I got it connecting to the other computer but it fails to launch. I'm getting 2 different messages one about the time out period expiring, and the other is the specified network name is no longer available.

Comment: Can you browser the file system on the machine or, if this is a web app, connect to the site in a browser?

Comment: Yes. It's just a virtual machine hosted on my main pc. I'm able to browse the file system of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem(s).

1. I was using the wrong PC name to connect to the host machine. I was using the Server name that you can type in the VS remote debugging monitor. I had it working when I did the server as 'Stephen@192.168...' where that was the actual ip address on my subnet
2. Windows didn't properly configure the firewall ports for me. I had to manually open the DCOM ports to get it connecting.
3. I had to clear the existing credentials for each machine once everything else was set up as is shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dbesfyx.aspx

Thanks everyone for your help and pointers.

Comment: #1 helped me - I was also using the server name